# Why the forward slash in image source is not working?

Tags: html, image, url, imagesource

I've a folder titled 'html_playground' inside folder 'www' which is my web root directory of Wampserver.

Inside the directory 'html_palyground' I have a a file titled 'demo.html' which contains following HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="/images/html5.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">

</body>
</html>
```

Inside the folder **'html_playground'** there is another folder titled **'images'** that contains an image file titled **'html5.gif'**

When I hit the URL `http://localhost/html_playground/demo.html` in my browser I'm not able to see the image **html5.gif**. Why so?

Then I tried with following HTML code :

```
<img src="images/html5.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
```

Then the image got displayed.

So, my question is why it's not working when I add forward slash at the beginning of src attribute's value? Am I making any mistake by adding a forward slash at the beginning of value of src attribute?

When should forward slash at the beginning in value of src attribute of image tag?

Someone please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward slash at the beginning instructs the browser to resolve the path relative to your web root directory on http://localhost/

As you mentioned in your comment this would correspond to the www/ directory on your file system. So `/html_playground/images/html5.gif` should work

Basically the forward slash is just appending the specified path to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is when there is a forward slash in your source path it gets resolved relative to the current directory. So it becomes `http://localhost/html_playground/images/html5.gif`. When there is no forward slash it is resolved relative to the root.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `./images/html5.gif` as well: a leading slash makes your path *absolute* when it is *relative* to `www/html_playground`

Moreover you must be careful with absolute path and experiment to know what is the root exactly: *filesystem*, *www*... it can depend on the webserver.